# How to break into Microservices

Tags: microservices

I am working on an application to create assessments for students. I want to use a microservices for this. However, I'm confused if Assessments and Questions go into the same micro service or should I split them. Every assessment contains a list of questions. But I feel that they come under the same domain and should come under the same micro service. Can some one help me decide.

Answer (score 1):

For breaking microservices, it is always preferred to with [Domain-driven design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design). If in your case, Assessments does not exist without Questions then it totally make sense to have them in same domain.